# django-toolbox: No module named from django.utils.importlib import import_module

Tags: django, mongodb, django-nonrel

I've the latest version of Django, django-toolbox and Python.
I'm using MongoDB as DB and PyMongo.
My problem is this:
"No module named from django.utils.importlib import import_module"

This happens because I want to use Embedded Models and specifically, Lists of Subobjects (One-to-Many Relations) as you can see [in the tutorial](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/embedded-models.html#lists-of-subobjects-one-to-many-relations).
Is there a way to solve this problem or to model the Lists of Subobjects in an another way?
Thanks.

EDIT: I switched to Django 1.8 but now my error is

```
"name basestring is not defined"
```

Answer (score 0):

The import

```
from django.utils.importlib import import_module
```

should be changed to

```
from importlib import import_module
```

I see you've opened a [GitHub issue 78](https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox/issues/78). Until that's fixed, you can use Django 1.8.

Comment: Choosing to change the library I get some other errors. I switched to Django 1.8. But now I get the error 'basestring' is not defined

Comment: That's a separate issue. It looks as if the library does not support Python 3 properly.